# Using and modifying Apex trigger variable in Apex Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Is it possible to use and modify any apex trigger variable in the apex test class ??

will the @TestVisible notation helps in this scenario ??

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented syntax for referencing variables declared within a trigger.

But a trigger can reference variables defined in a conventional Apex class and so can a test:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static Boolean flag = true;
}

trigger MyTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    if (MyClass.flag) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

@isTest
private class MyTriggerTest {
    @isTest
    static void test() {
        MyClass.flag = false;
        insert new Contact(FirstName = 'Jane', LastName = 'Doe');
        ...
    }
}
```

The @TestVisible doesn't help in this situation because the MyClass property (or method) has to be public to be referenced in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

@TestVisible allows you to see variables and methods that normally an outside class would not have access to.  So for example, if you had a utility class was used in your trigger, if you had private variables or private methods like below, they would not be accessible in the test class

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper {

    public void AccountBeforeInsert(list<Account> newAccounts){
        method1(newAccounts);
        method2(newAccounts);
    }

    private void method1(list<Account> accs) {
         //Your Logic
    }

    private void method2(list<Account> accs) {
         //Your Logic
    }

}
```

*With the class above if you tried this in your test class you would get an **exception** thrown*

```
@isTest
public class AccountTriggerHelperTest {

     static testmethod void myTest() {
          list<Account> mylist = new list<Account>();
          mylist.add(new Account(Name = 'Test'));
          AccountTriggerHelper.method1(mylist);
     }
}
```

*In order to clear this exception you just need to use the **@TestVisible** on the methods*

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper {

        public void AccountBeforeInsert(list<Account> newAccounts){
            method1(newAccounts);
            method2(newAccounts);
        }

        @TestVisible private void method1(list<Account> accs) {
             //Your Logic
        }

        @TestVisible private void method2(list<Account> accs) {
             //Your Logic
        }

    }
```

Now you will no longer get the exception.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

No, because triggers aren't real classes, there is no way to directly interact with them. Instead, use a utility class and reference those variables instead. You should note that only static variables will help you in this case.

```
trigger X on Y (after insert) {
    Yutil.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
}

public class Yutil {
    @testVisible static Boolean z = false;

    public static void afterInsert(Y[] records) {
        if(!z) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, it doesn't have to be a Boolean value, it could be any type of value, such as a DateTime value for a query, or string values, etc.